# Why does my cursor look like this when I RDP into a remote ubuntu 22.04 desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

the cursor is the square block thingy. I remoted into 2 of my ubuntu 22.04 desktops via RDP and the cursors looks the same on both of them.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the mouse pointer is the small square of random pixels on the right-hand side with the hotspot being the top-left of that square.  The colours of the pixels stay the same until the mouse pointer changes (e.g. on the edge of a window), but it's always a random square of colours which leads me to believe that this is some kind of corruption.  I think the offset of the mouse pointer image index reference could be calculated wrong (and therefore reading random bytes from memory) or the cursor dictionary could be not loaded properly from the catalog (like a malloc error).

Comment: In my particular case I see this with Apache Guacamole where Windows cursors are fine but Ubuntu ones not.   I can't seem to replicate it in Remmina so it's possible it's something client-side.

Comment: Apparently, Apache Guacamole provides a local cursor which is a layer over the top of the canvas.  I looked in the DOM and I can indeed see a "software-cursor" class and a base64 png image as the style.  I converted it to png and opened it and it is indeed a square of random dots.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Guacamole](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-1717). Certain FreeRDP servers (at least Gnome Remote Desktop) send cursors in a slightly different format than their Windows counterparts and Guacamole isn't currently handling that difference correctly.

Comment: An update: a fix was merged today, see https://github.com/apache/guacamole-server/pull/418